# ReactRouter is not being imported while using WebpackDevServer

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am starting to build a brand new React application. However, webpack fails to import `react-router`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```

First two lines work well, but the third one is highlighted and the tip says `Cannot find module 'react-router'`. Same when running webpack-dev-server. On the other hand, it works when using webpack to build the bundle.

I have tried `react-router` of versions 3.0.0 and 1.0.3, `history` package is installed, tried to specify full path to the module. Any other ideas?

Thanks.

P.S. Probably worth mentioning that I've started with this boilerplate https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-typescript-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is a typescript-related issue. I have just forgotten to install types for the router (`npm install --save-dev @types/react-router`).

Comment: I have the exact same issue but I am using Javascript instead of Typescript, do you know how can I import Link and ReactRouter ?